# How do i convert the uri from onActivityresult to real file path to import that file

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I am getting uri from `String path = uri.getPath()` as `/document/primary:Download/West Delhi Mis June.xlsx`

But When I write `File file = new File(path)` It throws `FileNotFoundException`. Please help.

This is my code:

```
public void getdata(File fil){

    try{
        Workbook w;
        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fil);
        Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
        for (int j = 1; j<sheet.getRows(); j++){

            Cell c1 = sheet.getCell(0,j);
            Cell c2 = sheet.getCell(1,j);
            Cell c3 = sheet.getCell(2,j);
            Cell c4 = sheet.getCell(3,j);
            Cell c5 = sheet.getCell(4,j);
            Cell c6 = sheet.getCell(5,j);
            Cell c7 = sheet.getCell(6,j);
            Cell c8 = sheet.getCell(7,j);
            Cell c9 = sheet.getCell(8,j);
            Cell c10 = sheet.getCell(9,j);
            Cell c11 = sheet.getCell(10,j);
            Cell c12 = sheet.getCell(11,j);
            Cell c13 = sheet.getCell(12,j);

            String date =  c1.getContents();
            String empid = c2.getContents();
            String project = c3.getContents();
            String name =  c4.getContents();
            String route =  c5.getContents();
            String cabno = c6.getContents();
            String location =  c7.getContents();
            String contact = c8.getContents();
            String gender =  c9.getContents();
            String duty =  c10.getContents();
            String shift =  c11.getContents();
            String cabtype =  c12.getContents();
            String zone =  c13.getContents();

            adb.insertRoastData(date,empid,project,name,route,cabno,location,contact,gender,duty,shift,cabtype,zone);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void performFileSearch() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    intent.setType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            String path = uri.getPath();
            InputStream dataStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the uri?

Comment: Replace ":" with "/", 
path.replace(":","/");

Comment: Through Android File Picker @codeFreak

Comment: This error occured -  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary/Download/West Delhi Mis June.xlsx (No such file or directory) doesn't help @Gautam

Answer (score 5):

You cannot convert a Uri to a File directly.
The Uri may not even contain the real, absolute path.

This is because it might have to go through a ContentProvider from a different app to serve you the actual file, all part of the new file security model from Nougat.

So what can you do? Let the OS open it as an InputStream:

```
Uri uri = ...
InputStream dataStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
// now buffer and read stream
```

Comment: It Gives error as -- openInputStream
(android.net.Uri)
in ContentResolver cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String) @RobCo

Comment: @user6698813: Pass the `Uri` into `openInputStream()`.

Comment: Right, made a typo. Thanks for the catch @CommonsWare